# Boolean function for True only if last True

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Is there any way how to get true only if second value is true?

```
| A | B | Result |
|---|---|--------|
| 0 | 0 | 0      |
| 0 | 1 | 1      |
| 1 | 0 | 0      |
| 1 | 1 | 0      |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `~A & B` would suffice.